# C# raise event when property changes in foreign class

Tags: c#, wpf, events, properties

I want to check if property changed in a class which isn't mine and doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged. This class is a part of an API and I want to raise event when Name property changes.

```
class SomethingChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    Something sth;
    string Name { get; set; }
    public SomethingChanged(Something Sth)
    {
        sth = Sth;
        Name = sth.Name;
        //do something to allow raise PropertyChangedEvent when sth.Name changes
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

I want to use it in WPF by the way (treeView). Is there any way to do that?

Or am I out of luck if that class (Something in example above) doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: 1. Do you expect assigning a value to `SomethingChanged.Name` to update the internal `Something.Name`? 2. Can `Something.Name` be changed without going through a function or property in `SomethingChanged` first?

Comment: 1. Nope, I don't want to do this, the other way around. 2. Yes. Actually it does. I just want to make SomethingChanged aware that property Name of field sth was modified outside.

Comment: 3. Is `Name` virtual (or be made virtual) in `Something` and would `SomethingChanged` being a subclass of `Something` be acceptable? (if you answer No to this then it is not possible if `Somthing` does not implment `INotifyPropertyChanged` and the answer to 2 was Yes)

Comment: No and no. Be also aware that API is using Something, if I were to extend it, I would acommplish nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately due to your constrains your only option is poling to see if the data has changed.

```
sealed class SomethingChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable
{
    private Something sth;
    private string _oldName;
    private System.Timers.Timer _timer;

    public string Name { get { return sth.Name; }

    public SomethingChanged(Something Sth, double polingInterval)
    {
        sth = Sth;
        _oldName = Name;
        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        _timer.AutoReset = false;
        _timer.Interval = polingInterval;
        _timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(_oldName != Name)
        {
           OnPropertyChanged("Name");
           _oldName = Name;
        }

        //because we did _timer.AutoReset = false; we need to manually restart the timer.
        _timer.Start();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var tmp = PropertyChanged; //Adding the temp variable prevents a NullRefrenceException in multithreaded environments.
        if (tmp != null)
            tmp(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if(_timer != null)
        {
            _timer.Stop();
            _timer.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that will do what I want to accomplish. It's very large workaround though. Also I believe it will be inefficient? But it's still better than nothing, thank you :)

Comment: Yes it is inefficient, but due to your constraints it is your only option. If I had my druthers I would look in to seeing if there is anything built in to the API or consuming the API in a different way (if it is a WCF call using different options for building the proxy class) so that it notifies me on the name change. But without more details on what kind of API you are working with (REST, WCF, a 3rd party DLL), this is the best you can do.

Comment: @user1577566 I made one last important change, the class is now disposable so it stops the timer when the class is disposed. (if you don't make the class `sealed` you will need to use the more standard [Dispose pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and add a `protected void Dispose(bool disposing)` method)

Comment: I looked for it, the only event I can see is onDocumentModified. When fired, I can use that to foreach SomethingChanged objects and check if property in Something changed. I will mark you answer as accepted since it does what I want.

Comment: Ideally, your `SomethingChanged` implementation could subscribe to `PropertyChanged` if the observed type (`Something`) implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and only fall back to polling if it doesn't.

Comment: @MikeStrobel If `Somthing` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` this class is pointless, if you already have the functionality, why are you using the wrapper class? :)

Comment: I didn't think there was enough context in the original question to assume this was the sole purpose for the wrapper.  And, even if it is, the wrapped type may not always be the same (what if `Something` is an interface?).  Just because the observed may not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` does not mean it _cannot_.

Comment: @MikeStrobel true, if there was a possibility that a subclass or implementation `Somthing` was passed in that did support it I would definitely use the existing `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation instead.